# $q.all not resolving second array element

Tags: angularjs, promise, q

I'm using $q.all as below to test my simple code. Some how $q is taking very long time to process the second one in the promise array and my backend server is timing out. When I see Network tab in the browser, getAccountStatementList is giving me 200 status where as getInvoiceDetails shows pending for ever before server timeout. How do I resolve this?

```
var promises = [$http.get('getAccountStatementList'), $http.get('getInvoiceDetails')];

$q.all(promises).then(function(values){
    console.log("Values 0 "+values[0]); // value alpha
    console.log("Values 1 "+values[1]); // value beta
    complete();
});
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your back-end server since it is never completing the second request.  It seems like you should be checking to see if the requests are properly formed from the client and if so, then examine the server code to see why it isn't completing the second request.

Comment: I was able to fetch the result if I run the second request directly in the browser, at the same time.

Comment: Also, I interchanged my promises array and now I get 200 status for getInvoiceDetails and getAccountStatementList shows pending

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `catch` callback to catch the error.

```
$q.all(promises).then(function(values){
    console.log("Values 0 "+values[0]); // value alpha
    console.log("Values 1 "+values[1]); // value beta
    complete();
}).catch(function(error){
   console.log(error)
})
```

the downfall of this is even if one promise rejected, it will immediately come to the `catch`. not waiting for the rest of the batch.

Comment: Tried this. but it's the same. Also, I interchanged my promises array and now I get 200 status for getInvoiceDetails and getAccountStatementList shows pending